# Maximum number of sides when cutting n sided polyhedron

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra

How can I calculate maximum number of sides that could be obtained by cutting n-sided polyhedron with a plane? For some reason, I was not able to find clear answer to this question online.

EDIT: I am particularly interested in convex case

Comment: If the polyhedron need not be convex, I estimate $n+n/3$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how did you come up with that estimate?

Comment: I thought of a polyhedron consisting of many pointy tetrahedra glued to at most two extra faces at the bottom and the plane cuts all tetrahedra near their tip

Comment: If you cut an $n$ sided convex polyhedron, the number of faces increases by at most one, of course